# Make Android MainActivity to wait for a thread to finish

Tags: android, multithreading, google-maps-markers, handler, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm exploring the **Google Maps Android Api v2**, and I found some troubles I am messing around with!

I am working with a LatLng array containing a route from a XML file.

I want the app to **simulate a car ride with the imported data**. (show a simple marker showing the 'current' position contained inside the array in a loop)

I found a method which **animates the marker** from one point to another. It works quite good when I am just working with two coordinates, but it gets crazy when I work with the whole array!

I guess it is because the **handler**, in the animateMarker method.

So, my question is, **how can I make the make the main thread to wait the animateMarker to finish, in order to see the simulated route properly.**

Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GoogleMap mMap;
ArrayList<LatLng> coordinates;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /**
     * Here I import the LatLng array from an XML file
     */


    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    Marker myMarker;

    myMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(coordinates.get(0)));

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinates.get(0),17));

    for(int i=0;i<coordinates.size()-1;i++){
         animateMarker(myMarker, coordinates.get(i+1), false);
         mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinates.get(i),17));
    }


 }

/**
 * 
 * @param marker
 * @param toPosition
 * @param hideMarker
 * @return 
 */
public  void animateMarker(final Marker marker, final LatLng toPosition,
        final boolean hideMarker) {

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    final LatLng startLatLng= marker.getPosition();
    final long duration = 2000;

    final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void  run() {
            long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                    / duration);
            double lng = t * toPosition.longitude + (1 - t)
                    * startLatLng.longitude;
            double lat = t * toPosition.latitude + (1 - t)
                    * startLatLng.latitude;
            marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));

            if (t < 1.0) {
                // Post again 16ms later.
                handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
            } else {
                if (hideMarker) {
                    marker.setVisible(false);
                } else {
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }

            }
        }

    });

}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use AsyncTask

here is an example

```
     private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
         protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
             int count = urls.length;
             long totalSize = 0;
             for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                 totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
                 publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
                 // Escape early if cancel() is called
                 if (isCancelled()) break;
             }
             return totalSize;
         }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Once created, a task is executed very simply:

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

Comment: I tried, but what do you mean?, including the for loop inside the doInBackground method? or just filling it with a thread.sleep??